# Trouble with extracting data from a CSV file, sorting it and then writing that sorted list into another CSV file

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I'm trying to read data from a CSV file, sort it in python and then write it into another CSV file. I'm unsure of how to split the list I've sorted into the correct columns.

The output file prints out the complete list and I don't know how to split the list and output it into the csv file for each column.

Here's a snippet of the CSV file

```
Jack,M,1998

Bill,F,2006

Kat,F,1999

Jess,F,2009

Alexander,M,1982
```

and my code to give some insight on what I'm trying to do.

```
import csv
import operator

   US = open('Test.csv', 'r')#Unsorted
   S = open('TestSorted.csv', 'w')#Sorted

def sortinput():
            option = input('Sort by name, gender or year?: ')
            if option == "name":
                choice = 0
            elif option == "gender":
                choice = 1
            elif option == "year":
                choice = 2
            else:
                print('Invalid Input')

            csv1 = csv.reader(US, delimiter=',')
            sort = sorted(csv1, key=operator.itemgetter(choice))

            for eachline in sort:
                    print (eachline)

            with S as csvfile:
                    fieldnames = ['Name', 'Gender', 'Year']
                    csv2 = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
                    csv2.writeheader()
                    for eachline in sort:
                            csv2.writerow({'Name': sort[0] ,'Gender': sort[1],'Year':sort[2][enter image description here][1]})
```

Comment: What precisely does *"Trouble with"* mean? Give a [mcve].

Comment: Step 1: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Oh right, sorry. The output file prints out the complete list and I don't know how to split the list and output it into the csv file for each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `sort[0]`, etc.:

```
    for eachline in sort:
        csv2.writerow({'Name': sort[0], 'Gender': sort[1], 'Year': sort[2]})
```

you meant `eachline[0]`, etc.:

```
    for eachline in sort:
        csv2.writerow({'Name': eachline[0], 'Gender': eachline[1], 'Year': eachline[2]})
```

(`sort[0]`, `sort[1]`, and `sort[2]` refer to three whole lines of the file, not to the three fields of one line.)

Once you've fixed that, the CSV output looks like what you want:

```
Name,Gender,Year
Alexander,M,1982
Bill,F,2006
Jack,M,1998
Jess,F,2009
Kat,F,1999
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was close but I couldn't figure out what was off. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `csv.DictWriter`, you could use `csv.writer`. The loop would look like below

```
  with S as csvfile:
      fieldnames = ['Name', 'Gender', 'Year']
      csv2 = csv.writer(csvfile,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
      csv2.writerow(fieldnames)
      csv2.writerow(sort)
```